# Python is replacing all _ when I only need one replaced

Tags: python

```
#HangMan - 2014
import random
import time

secret = ""
dash = ""

def create_hangman():
    #List of words, pick a word, then set it to a var
    words = ["soccer", "summer", "windows", "lights", "nighttime", "desktop", "walk"]
    d = random.randint(0, 6)

    #Tell the compiler we want the global secret var
    global secret
    #Change the global secret v to a string while we choose the word
    secret = str(words[d])

    #The blank spaces. Find how many letters the word is and replace it with underscores
    create_hangman.dash = "_ " * len(secret)

    #Print the hangman
    print('''
            O
        ----|----   
            |
           [|]
           [ ]

    ''', create_hangman.dash, secret)

def guess(letter):
    #If the guess is in the word...
    if(letter in secret):
        print("Congratulations!", letter, " was found!")
        edit_blanks(letter)
    else:
        print(letter, "is not in the secret word!")

def edit_blanks(letter):
    #BUG: If there is more then one letter it shows -1. Make an if statement to see if there is more than one letter in it
    #Need to find what number the letter is in the secret word
    word_location = secret.find(letter)
    #Now from the location of the correct word find the location in the dashs
    dash_letter = create_hangman.dash[word_location * 2]
    #Replace the correct dash to the letter
    create_hangman.dash = create_hangman.dash.replace(dash_letter, letter)
    #BUG: This replaces all _'s not just the one Ex: from _ _ _ _ _ to a a a a a when it should be _ a _ _ _ 
    print(create_hangman.dash)

def wrong_word(letter):
    #TODO: Make a peice on the hangman
    print("")

name = input("Whats your name? ")
print("Hey", name, "welcome to HangMan 1.2")
create_hangman()
think = input("Pick a letter: ")
guess(think)
```

Alright, so I am having a problem with the code above. This is my first python project and I am having a problem with this bit here:

```
def edit_blanks(letter):
    #BUG: If there is more then one letter it shows -1. Make an if statement to see if there is more than one letter in it
    #Need to find what number the letter is in the secret word
    word_location = secret.find(letter)
    #Now from the location of the correct word find the location in the dashs
    dash_letter = create_hangman.dash[word_location * 2] #I use * 2 because there is a space _ _
    #Replace the correct dash to the letter
    create_hangman.dash = create_hangman.dash.replace(dash_letter, letter)
    #BUG: This replaces all _'s not just the one Ex: from _ _ _ _ _ to a a a a a when it should be _ a _ _ _ 
    print(create_hangman.dash)
```

I don't get an error from this, but it doesn't do what I need it to do. I am trying to get it to replace the _ _ _ _ _ with a letter in case they get the correct letter so from, _ _ _ _ _ _ to _ u _ _ _ *.
What I think would fix this is instead of getting the '*' with        dash_letter = create_hangman.dash[word_location * 2]        I would get the index number of it. But I am not sure how to do that, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a list of underscores and then replace them by index. Then when you have to print out the list to the console just use `''.join(list)`. So maybe something like this as your remove dash function? All I'm doing is first creating a blank list of underscores the same length as the word and then you can simply run the remove_dash function for whichever letter needs to be replaced.

```
word = 'telephone'
hangman_dash = ['_' for x in range(len(word))]
def remove_dash(letter):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            hangman_dash[i] = letter

remove_dash('e')
print hangman_dash
print ''.join(hangman_dash)
```